# Automatic scrolling for keyboard?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard

I am working on an iPhone app with autolayout that has an upper and a lower field at the bottom of a view. The user taps a field and I have to scroll the view up above the keyboard. Here is my keyboardDidShow code.

```
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize kbSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    [[self scrollView] setContentInset:contentInsets];

    [self setIsKeyboardVisible:YES];
}
```

Not only should this not work (I left out the actual scroll command), but when I tap the upper field the view scrolls upward until the bottom of that field is at the top of the keyboard. When I tap Next on the keyboard to move the cursor to the lower field, the view scrolls upward a little more until the bottom of the lower field is at the top of the keyboard.

Here's how I handle the Return key:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
    switch ([textField tag])
    {
        case vtNameField:
            [[self txtEmail] becomeFirstResponder];

            break;

        case vtEmailField:
            [[self txtEmail] resignFirstResponder];

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Does anybody know what is causing the scrolling? I see this behavior in other apps and I thought it had to be hand coded. I am seeing this in only one view of mine and I wonder if it is due to something I have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library it's super easy and no need for code.
Just make the class name of the view as "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView" and the view will automatically scroll to make the TextField above the keyboard.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding